# conditional trigger mysql

Tags: sql, mysql, triggers

I want to make the code that if any of new column's value is null
change that one to the value of row before with trigger event

```
CREATE TRIGGER updateField BEFORE INSERT ON message
       FOR EACH ROW 
 
       IF (NEW.COLUMN IS NULL) then
       set NEW.COLUMN = SELECT THE_COLUMN FROM Table ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 1;
       
       END IF
```

Comment: To use a subquery as a value, you have to put it in `()`: `set NEW.COLUMN = (SELECT ...)`

Comment: Yeah but still I have errors in my code, I think the structure of if statement is wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must also have a `BEGIN` and `END`
if you have more than a code line

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER updateField BEFORE INSERT ON message
       FOR EACH ROW 
         BEGIN
               IF (NEW.COLUMN IS NULL) then
                    set NEW.COLUMN = (SELECT THE_COLUMN FROM Table1 ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 1);       
               END IF;
        END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use a [compound statement](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-compound-statements.html) like `IF/THEN/END IF`, you must put the body of the trigger in a `BEGIN..END` block.

```
...

FOR EACH ROW BEGIN

   IF (NEW.COLUMN IS NULL) THEN
     SET NEW.COLUMN = (SELECT THE_COLUMN FROM Table ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 1);
   
   END IF;
END
```